# How do I create a Google Action intent that redirects Google Home to a radio station?

Tags: redirect, android-intent, action, internet-radio

I work for a tv/radio broadcasting company, and we stream live content through various devices through a web-based API, and we also stream through internet radio (such as iHeartRadio, Tunein, etc.). The API can also return things like show titles and descriptions.

I've been tasked with creating a Google Action that can be used to retrieve information from the API such as what's playing, what's coming up next, what shows are available, etc. It would be fantastic if Google Actions supported live-streamed content, but I believe they do not.

Since we DO stream through internet radio, I would like to create an intent that allows the user to be redirected from my action to the internet radio stream for our station. How would I go about doing that? I *could* simply tell the user to start a new conversation (e.g., "Say, OK Google, play 'My-Awesome-Radio'"), but it would be more user-friendly not to have to start a new conversation.